# How to get the previous month date in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get the previous months date in asp.net which means that if the current date is 5/2/2013 then I want to display the previous date as 5/1/2013. How to solve this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this :

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
d = d.AddMonths(-1);
```

Comment: One liner: DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1); Also, depending on if your server side is utc or not, you may want to use DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-1);

Answer (score 14):

The solution is to substract 1 month:

```
DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)
```

Or if not just build the datetime object from scratch:

```
var previousDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonth(-1);

var date = new DateTime(previousDate.Year, previousDate.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
```

this time you are guaranteed that the year and month are correct and the day stays the same. (although this is not a safe algorithm due to cases like the 30th of march and the previous date should be 28/29th of February, so better go with the first sugeestion of substracting a month)

Answer (score 5):

If you already have date time in string format

```
var strDate = "5/1/2013";
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, 
                                   "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var lastMonthDateTime = dateTime.AddMonths(-1);
```

else if you have `DateTime` object just call it's `AddMonths(-1)` method.